# in django how can i order multiple 'child' model at the same time

Tags: django, inheritance, model

I have this kind of code:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(_('pub_date'),default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class A(Base):
    ...
class B(Base):
    ...
```

how can i do ,if i want to order A and B instances in the same time ? thxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't combine queries on children of an abstract class. You will need to chain the result afterwards either by converting to sequences and adding, or via `itertools.chain()`.